# select and merge active record id for a table

Tags: oracle

Table1 is as below

```
ID Name PID updateDT
-----------------------
1  A    26  21-Jan-2018 
2  A    26  21-Dec-2017
3  A    26  <null>
4  B    45  <Null>
5  B    45  21-Dec-2017
```

wanted to write a query so that the result would be

```
ID Name PID updateDT    Lt_Record(Active record ID)
----------------------------------------
1  A    26  21-Jan-2018  3
2  A    26  21-Dec-2017  3
3  A    26  <null>       3
4  B    45  <Null>       4
5  B    45  21-Dec-2017  4
```

Please help

Comment: You have showed us zero effort here.  You should at least tell us what the logic is behind the expected `Lt_Record` column.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i wanted to group the record and identify the active record using null value of updated date.

Comment: the result should be

Comment: ID Name PID updateDT    Lt_Record(Active record ID)
----------------------------------------
1  A    26  21-Jan-2018  3
2  A    26  21-Dec-2017  3
3  A    26  <null>       3
4  B    45  <Null>       5
5  B    45  21-Dec-2017  5

Comment: NO!  Don't paste data here, edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `first_value()` function for that:

```
select id, name, pid, updatedt, 
       first_value(id) over (partition by pid order by updatedt desc nulls last) as lt_record
from the_table
order by pid, updatedt desc nulls last;
```

Online example: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d10412a2dc0aed9ee9c21d407d12b40c